# NPE при назначении экземпляра класса OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, listener

У меня есть списковое представление

```
private ListView drawerList;
```

Ему я пытаюсь назначить свой класс наследующий от ListView.OnItemCLickListener

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        selectItem(position);
        setActionBarTitle(position);
    }
};
```

Присваиваю его

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());//Здесь вылетает NPE
}
```

Но у меня вылетает NPE.
Что не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не инициализировали вашу переменную, оттого она `null` и вы получаете `NPE` при попытке вызова её метода. Вам надо инициализировать её, найдя в разметке вашу вьюху по её `ID`

```
drawerList = findViewById(R.id.ТУТ_ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР_ВЬЮХИ_ИЗ_РАЗМЕТКИ);
```